# Putting icon instead of " + " or " - " in an accordian menu.js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui-accordion

I am making an accordian menu.
I just found this link http://jsfiddle.net/zM5Vj/ , and it is almost similar to the accordian menu I have made.
In the code, where there is

```
if($(this).text() == "-")  
{
  $(this).text("+");
  }
  else {
  $('#accordion .opener').text("+");
  $(this).text("-");
   }
 });
```

If insted of "+" and "-", i want to put icons "~/Image/iconplus.gif" and "~/Image/iconminus.gif". How do i do so?
I have tried

```
<img src="..."/>
```

But still it is of no use.
Please can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess there is no option to do so using jquery alone, we need to have css also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).text()` allows you to specify plain text content for an element. To attach an image, use `$(this).append($(<img src='plus.gif'))`.

Also, instead of using `$(this).text() == '-'` to see if the menu has been expanded, attach a class to the `<a>` element.

For example, we can use `.addClass('expand')` to indicate that the menu has expanded, and then `.hasClass('expand')` to check whether the menu has expanded, and finally `'.removeClass('expand')` to indicate that the menu is no longer expanded).

Here's an example, using dummy images to illustrate:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SiCurious/zM5Vj/24/)

```
$(function(){

    //starter plus image
    var startPlus = $('<img>').attr('src','http://findicons.com/files/icons/1688/web_blog/48/add.png')
                              .css({'height': '20px', 'width': '20px'});

    $('#accordion .fullChild>a.opener').addClass('box')
                                       .append(startPlus);

    $('#accordion .opener').click(function() {

        //images for click event handler
        var plusImg = $('<img>').attr('src','http://findicons.com/files/icons/1688/web_blog/48/add.png')
                                .css({'height': '20px', 'width': '20px'});
        var minusImg = $('<img>').attr('src','http://findicons.com/files/icons/2083/go_green_web/64/subtract.png')
                                .css({'height': '10px', 'width': '10px'});

        if($(this).hasClass('expand')) {
            $(this).empty()
                   .append(plusImg)
                   .removeClass('expand');
        } else {
            $(this).empty()
                   .append(minusImg)
                   .addClass('expand');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank You All for responding and helping me in solving it.
@Simon Adcock, Your answer gave me a new way to think about the solution.
However, i also found a 1 line solution to it.
I just added this line to my *.js* file

```
 $(this).append($('<img src="../Images/imageplus.gif"/>'))
```

So, answer finally it is :

```
if (x == "block") {
        $(this).text('');
        $(this).append($('<img src="../Images/imageplus.gif"/>'))
        $(this).append(' ' + valueText);
    }
    else {
        $(this).text('');
        $(this).append($('<img src="../Images/imageminus.gif"/>'))
        $(this).append(' ' + valueText);
    }
```